# Use SSL only on one file in iis 7.5?

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl, iis-7.5

I have a website hosted on an IIS 7.5/Server 2008 R2 Server. I want to use SSL and Basic Authentication on one file in the site. This used to be easy on sub-7 IIS versions, how can I do it on 7.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable, File Level Authentication in IIS 7 / 7.5

- Go the Web Site
- Click Content View
- Right click on the file e.g. iisstart.htm -> Switch to Features View
- Double click Authentication
- Now, select the Authentication Type you want to configure

Follow the same procedure for SSL Settings as well to enable SSL for just a single file.

Source: http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Enable-File-Level-Authentication-in-IIS-7-75.aspx